# Define a bijective map that is linear and a ring morphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $V$ a $\mathbb{K}-$vecor space with dim$(V) = 1.$ I need to show that there exists a bijective mapping, $$A: L(V,V) \rightarrow \mathbb{K},$$ which is linear and represents a ring morphism. I also need to show that if this is the case, the composition of mappings in $L(V,V)$ corresponds to the multiplication in $\mathbb{K}$ and that $L(V,V)$ is a field.

Let $f,g \in L(V,V)$ be two linear mappings, $f,g: V \rightarrow V.$ Since dim$(V) = 1,$ any vector $v \in V$ is a basis vector of $V.$ One has to define somehow $A.$ Unfortunately, there is no inner product given. We define $A$ as follows: $A(f)(v):= a,$ for $f(v) = av$ once a basis was chosen in $V$ and $a \in \mathbb{K}.$ We check first that $A$ is linear: $A(f+g)(v) = a+b, $ for $f(v)=av, g(v)=bv.$ Thus, $A(f+g)(v) = A(f)(v) + A(g)(v).$ Also, $A(\alpha f)(v) = \alpha a = \alpha A(f)(v).$ We know that dim$L(V,V)=$dim $V\cdot$dim$V = 1.$ Thus, each linear mapping $f\in L$ can be considered as basis of $L.$ We first show that ker$(A) = 0,$ i.e. the zero linear mapping. ker$(A) = \{ f\in L : A(f)(v) = 0 \in \mathbb{K}\}.$ Given the definition of $A, f(v) = 0v.$ Thus, $f$ is the zero mapping. It follows that $A$ is injective. Since both $L, \mathbb{K}$ are vecor spaces with identical (finite) dimension, $A$ is surjective and thus bijective. How one would show that $A$ represents a ring morphism ? We already shoed that $A$ is addition preserving by its linearity. It remains to be shown that it is multiplication and unit preserving. Let $A(fg)(v):=ab,$ for $f(v)=av, g(v)=bv.$ It follows, $A(fg)(v)=ab=A(f)(v) A(g)(v).$ Also, $A(1_L)(v) = 1 \in \mathbb{K},$ given that $1_L (v) =1v.$
Now I need to show that composition of mappings in $L$ corresponds to the multiplication in $\mathbb{K}.$ But given the definition $A(fg)(v)=ab=A(f)(v) A(g)(v),$ I guess this was already shown.

Finally, for showing that $L$ is a field, I need to show $f \in L, f \neq 0, \implies f$ is a unit. For $f \in L, f(v)=av,$ it suffices to take $g(v) = \frac {1}{a}v.$

I am unsure I provided a consistent definition of $A.$ Can somebody provide a comment ? Thanks.

Comment: It is important that you specify that the basis vector $v$ is non-zero. Also, note that the "dim" and "ker" operators are available in Latex as `\dim` and `\ker`.

Comment: Similarly, $\{f\}$ is only a basis for $L(V,V)$ if $f$ is not the zero-mapping.

Comment: From my reading, your solution is correct but just gets slightly unfocused at the end. You define $A(fg)(v)$ as $ab$, but the group operation is already fixed as composition and so I don't see how adding a new definition is appropriate, even if you do show that this definition is equivalent to composition.

Comment: I suspect that it would have been easier to define the inverse of $A$, for example one could write $A^{-1}(a)(kv) = akv$ for all $a,k \in \Bbb K$ and some chosen non-zero vector $v \in V$.

Comment: @user I agree with Milo's comment: instead of **defining** $A(fg)(v) := ab$, you should **show** that $A(fg) = ab$.

Comment: @user Also, it is better to write "$A(f) := a$, for $f(v) = av$". Otherwise, it seems as though $A(f)$ is a linear map rather than a scalar. $A(f(v))$ is slightly better, but because $v$ refers to a specific choice of vector, $f(v)$ looks like it refers to a vector, which means that it looks like $A$ is a map from $V$ to $V$.

Comment: Many thanks for the both comments. If we stick to a single definition of $A,$ i.e. $A(f):=a$ if $f(v) = av, v\neq 0,$ in order to show $A(fg) = ab$ we first set $(fg)(v) := ab v. $ It follows, $A(fg) = ab.$ Is this sufficient ? I thus provide a single definition of $A$ for both the linear as well as the ring structure.

Comment: @user249018 No, again you're doing something strange. The point is that if $f$ is the function defined so that $f(x) = ax$ for all $x \in V$ and $g$ is the function defined so that $g(x) = bx$ for all $x \in V$, then it follows that $f(g(x)) = abx$ for all $x \in V$, which is to say that $(fg)(v) = abv$ holds **as a consequence of** the definitions of $f$ and $g$. You should not be setting $fg$ equal to anything directly.